# Simple error with underscore

Tags: javascript, web-services, backbone.js, underscore.js

Please could someone tell me why line 1 below throws the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'age' of undefined.
```

I am new to javascript and backbone and this error makes no sense to me.

Thanks

```
<script>
var Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("Person is initialized");
    }
});

var People = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Person,

    initialize: function(){
        console.log("People model is initialized");
    }
});

var person = new Person({age: 12});
var person2 = new Person({age: 15});
var person3 = new Person({age: 12});
var people = new People();
people.add(person);
people.add(person2);

// (1) var ages = _.where(people, {age: 12});
console.log(ages); 
</script>
```

Comment: It is not a backbone/underscore issue, but rather a basic JS one. You're trying to read a property named `age` from a reference that has the value of `undefined`.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Please can you explain. I am unclear about your response. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what is undefined here. The person objects are all defined. Then they are added to people(which is a defined collection object). I thought console.log would print an array of person objects with the attribute age = 12 ??

Comment: If the error comes from `_.where(people...` then `people` apparently has an `undefined` index. Try `console.log(people)` and check its contents.

Comment: That's the thing - console.log(people) produces d {models: Array[3], length: 3, _byId: Object, _idAttr: "id", constructor: function…}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want this:

```
var ages = people.where({age: 12});
```

[Underscore's `where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where) and [Backbone Collection's `where`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where) are two different things.

Like Fabricio said, the error means some code is trying to read a property of undefined.  Something like `foo.age` where `foo` is `undefined` will produce this error.

Since you say you are new to javascript... In Chrome dev tools, you can click the error and it will take you to where the error occurred.  In this case it takes you to underscore's source code.  When an error occurs in a library, 99% of the time (if the library is widely used) it means you are using something wrong, and can check the documentation to see what is going on.

Comment: This has tangled me up more times than I'd like to admit :P